# How can I type in half-width number in Japanese Kana keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, japanese

I want to type in numbers on Japanese Kana input keyboard, but it needs alt key to type in numbers. For example, to type in 3, you must type in Alt + 3.

However, this 3 is full-width, and it even does not go into the conversion list mode. So I found that it is not possible to type in the numbers in half-width.

Is this possible in Japanese Kana keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

[This Apple doc](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22646) says you should uncheck the box for Full Width numbers in the Japanese keyboard Preferences.

[image]

However this does not seem to work with Kana input (presumably a bug).  As a workaround, you can use the Convert Text to Half Width service (turned on in system preferences/keyboard/shortcuts/services).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does this really work? In my case, it gets me the full-width (if I use Romaji mode, it turns to the half-width...).

Comment: Must be a bug with Kana input.  You have to use the Convert to Text to Half Width service (turned on in system preferences/keyboard/shortcuts/services)